# Pentaho Kettle replace cell value if value exists in other two columns

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Am using **Pentaho BI server** with **Data Integration** to get data set and merge data from two input tables, Now i need to **replace value** of cell in each row, **if two other columns** in the same row matches my criteria, how can i accomplish this with Kettle?

I need to match many values with the cell value in each row, values to be matched with the cell are inside an excel sheet.

I have tried using **Replace in string** component but it does not work :( can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do compound tests with the `Filter Rows` step. For a result that passes you can follow up with a `Set Field Value` step. It would look something like this:

[image: If Two pass]

The way to get the "AND" condition in the `Filter Rows` step is to click on the little icon on the far upper right of the condition box. Note also that you must supply a value for 'ReplaceVal' earlier in the transform (I just hard coded it in the `Data Grid`).

EDIT: Based on the wording of your question, your criteria is a simple null check. "IS NULL" is one of the conditions available in the `Filter Rows` step.

Comment: i need to check if two of the columns has a certain value, i need to replace 3rd column in the row with a -ve value.